# Need to restructure JSON database or make single query(Firebase)

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have 2 branches in my JSON tree, which look like this:

```
users {
    profile-data {
           user-key {
                //here is users profile fields like nickname and other
           }
           ......
    }
    friends {
        user-key {
            friend's-user-key:true
            another-friend's-user-key:true
            ......
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is to fetch all users-profile data of users, that are friends of any user. I didn't find the way to fetch all this data by 1 query so I need to write something like this:

```
usersFriendsRef.child("userId").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String userId = child.getKey();
                     usersProfileDataRef.child(userId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        ////Only here i can get user's profile data    
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
```

So the problem is that I need to make many requests to fetch friends' profile data one by one, so I need to restructure my database or find the way to write this as 1 query

Answer (score 2):

That's the correct way in which you can achieve this. There's no problem with nested queries. You need to find all those id's and then based on them, to query. I could move the `friends` node under `profile-data -> user-key` to create a single query but knowing that in Firebase is best to have the data as flatten as possible, it's not a solution.

Keep in mind not to forget to remove the listener, when it's no more needed, like this:

```
databaseReference.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);
```

Hope it helps.