# How to properly retrieve value from Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following data structure:

[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDldm.png)

`name` could have an unlimited number of children.

And the code below:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();    
DatabaseReference dirFire = rootRef.child("messages").child("name");

 dirFire.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    String name = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
    //do what you want with the name
 }

 @Override
 public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

 }
 });
```

With the code above, I can't retrieve the value of `name`. How can I retrieve `name` if the `key` is unknown to the client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use this code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();    
DatabaseReference messagesRef = rootRef.child("messages");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String key = ds.getKey();

            DatabaseReference keyRef = rootRef.child("messages").child(key).child("name");
            ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot ds1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String name = ds1.getValue(String.class);
                        Log.d("TAG", name);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
            };
            keyRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
messagesRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

**Edit:** Here is another approach using a solution that looks like an earlier one.

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();    
DatabaseReference messagesRef = rootRef.child("messages");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            for (DataSnapshot nameSnapshot : ds.child("name").getChildren()) {
                String name = nameSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                Log.d("TAG", name);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
messagesRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

The output will be:

```
John Miche
Joe Mitch
Sabr. A
Luis Jean
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But, in my case, `name` has many children so this won't work. Can you adjust your code, please?

Comment: I will write you some code but I need to see the other childrens too.

Comment: I updated the question. Note that `name` could have a number of children that can vary.

Comment: It cannot be, because Firebase database is structured as a pair of key and value. You only have keys which its note permitted in Firebase. Please give us a real screenshot.

Comment: Yes a key is in front of these values indeed. Sorry for that editing mistake.

Comment: Question edited - 
I edited the image for privacy reasons.

Comment: Please tell me if something's missing, Alex. I will immediately accept your answer once the issue is solved :)

Comment: Thanks, but I think you forgot to add `"name"` somewhere, am I right?

Comment: Thanks! Let me try this and let you know soon.

Comment: I get error: `Incompatible types` `Required <String,  java.langObject>`

Comment: `Found <String, java.lang.String>`

Comment: Are you sure you have multiple names in that node? Can please give us a screenshot? This error means that you have only one, as describes first time.

Comment: I get this error inside Android Studio without even building the APK. Let me show you:

Comment: Yes. One new update made. `for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {` Changed String with Object. Give it a try.

Comment: Another error at: `String name = entry.getValue();`
error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to String

Comment: Updated again. Sorry for this, but i'm actually wrting code, not testing. Changed `String name = entry.getValue().toString();`

Comment: I get error when I open the APK: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Set java.util.Map.entrySet()' on a null object reference` at `for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {`

Comment: Ok, i'm looking now.

Comment: I think you are making unnecessary query in your loop, you already have all the data downloaded.

Comment: You think or you are sure?

Comment: @Linxy Please elaborate.

Comment: @JonathanDoe first VEL downloads entire message node containing all children, so inner VEL is downloading already downloaded data again.

Comment: This ia about nested queries and is nothing wrong within Firebase. You can take a look at my answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44885306/need-to-restructure-json-database-or-make-single-queryfirebase/44887945).

Comment: @Linxy Please suggest a better alternative in a **new** answer.

Comment: I have added another solution, using a for loop. The fact is, that because you can have an unlimited number of childrens in `name` node, to get them, t's mandatory to iterate. The initial question was with only one child. So, you can give it a try.

Answer (score 3):

Obtain your data into hashMap..

```
  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("messages")
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot rootSnapshot) {
                    if (rootSnapshot.exists()) {
                        final Map<String, Map<String, String>> messageNameMap = new HashMap<>();
                        for (DataSnapshot messageSnapshot : rootSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            final String messageKey = messageSnapshot.getKey();
                            HashMap<String, String> nameMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            if (messageSnapshot.child("name").exists()) {
                                for (DataSnapshot nameSnapshot : messageSnapshot.child("name").getChildren()) {
                                    final String nameKey = nameSnapshot.getKey();
                                    final String nameValue = nameSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                                    nameMap.put(nameKey, nameValue);
                                }
                            }
                            if (!nameMap.isEmpty()) {
                                messageNameMap.put(messageKey, nameMap);
                            }
                        }

                        if (!messageNameMap.isEmpty()) {
                            // Here messageNameMap contains your data as such

                            // key: -Ko8bLawP4... val: Map Containing: 
                            //                          key: -Ko8wk... val: Jonathan Smith
                            //                          key: -Ko8wk... val: Kapler Moe
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```