# How to retrieve values from a Firebase Realtime Database with same fields(only values of that particular field) into a text view in android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: This is how my database looks like]

What I really need is to show every value in the "Income" field in `TextView`.

250
105

Is this possible? If it is possible please help me.

This is how I insert values to database

```
private void addReport() {

    Float total_Income = Float.valueOf(tv_total_income.getText().toString());
    String current_date = tv_current_date.getText().toString();
    
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");
    String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
    


    FirebaseDatabase mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference mDbRef = mDatabase.getReference("Reports"+"/"+currentDateandTime+"/"+current_date).child("Date");
    mDbRef.setValue(current_date);
    DatabaseReference mDbRef1 = mDatabase.getReference("Reports"+"/"+currentDateandTime+"/"+current_date).child("Income");
    mDbRef1.setValue(total_Income);

}
```

Comment: Can You try and elaborate what are you trying to say?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44889135/6280156

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Sairaj Sawant's answer might work, keep in mind that there is no need to attach a listener at every iteration of the loop. A more convenient solution is to attach a listener only once, like in the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference juneRef = rootRef.child("Reports").child("June");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String totalIncome = "";
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            totalIncome = totalIncome + ds.child("Income").getValue(String.class) + " ";
            
        }
        Log.d("TAG", totalIncome);
        textView.setText(totalIncome);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
juneRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

This code will work only if the `Income` property is of type String, as it is set in your `20-06-2020` child. However, the above code will **not** work if the value is set as an `Integer` as it set in your second `21-06-2020` child. Remember, both types of values must match. You either set both as String and the above code will work, or you set them as numbers, case in which you should use this line:

```
totalIncome = totalIncome + ds.child("Income").getValue(Long.class) + " ";
```

Comment: I have one more doubt also can i find the sum of that values? Like Total Income?

Comment: Sure you can. Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47632394/5246885)** out.

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing the children of `June` under `Reports` and looping through to get `income` as below :

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();    
DatabaseReference reportsRef = rootRef.child("Reports").child("June");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String key = ds.getKey();
            DatabaseReference keyRef = rootRef.child(key).child("income");
            ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot ds1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String income = ds1.getValue(String.class);
                        Log.d("TAG", income);
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
            };
            keyRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
reportsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Comment: Would better to add a child event listener and maintain an ArrayList of all the values.

Comment: I tried it but doesnt work... Untill @Alex Mamo Suggested a change in the code.Now everything works perfectly.. Thanks for helping me...